# integrating BIRT Actuate's iHub via JS API

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, birt

I came across [this](https://github.com/ActuateBIRT/AviatioExample) example with further explanations [here](http://developer.actuate.com/be/documentation/ihub31-dev/WebApp/index.html#page/WebApp/web-restapi.4.2.html). I have notices that the username and password is hard coded into the [main.js](https://github.com/ActuateBIRT/AviatioExample/blob/aviatioMaster/js/main.js). Is this a good idea? IMHO opinion it is not.

I am thinking about integrating BIRT into ASP.NET MVC. Maybe there are more secure ways of doing things. Any suggestion would be very much welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of methods to get a user's authentication information and then use that to request an AuthID from your report server. It depends on what functionality you want to give your user. If your users only need read access you can lock down the user account on your server. Use HTTPS to reach the report server for better security.

Comment: Please explain the life cycle with this use case: Login screen ASP.NET MVC, remaining interaction JavaScript. Are you suggesting to create the JavaScript dynamically server side whilst including the AuthID obtained during server side authentication?

Comment: If you do not want an anonymous user account you can request the authentication information on the client side and then pass that to the server. If the connection is using HTTPS, then the parameters in the URL are encrypted as well.

The JavaScript can also display a log in dialog or you can make your own and pass the values when accessing the server. 

Keeping the JavaScript authentication server side only works if it already knows the authentication information, in which case using the authid server side would avoid the HTTPS concerns - such as the browser or server caching the URL.